# Не находит переменную с объектом

Tags: php, ооп

Подключаю в методе одного класса другой класс в котором возвращаю объект, и метод в котором подключаю этот класс в дальнейшем эту переменную не видит. В чем проблема?

```
<?php

namespace Test\_Private;

use Test\Configuration   as T_Config;
use Test\Core            as T_Core;

class Module
{

    public function GetServiceSubscrModule($module)
    {
        require_once(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'.php');

        var_dump($obj);
        die;
    }

    public function CheckServiceSubscrModule($moduleName)
    {
       $module = $this->GetServiceSubscrModule($moduleName);
    }
}

namespace Test\_Private;

use Test\Configuration   as T_Config;
use Test\Core            as T_Core;

class Main_Module
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}

$obj = new Main_Module();
```

UPDATE: В чем заключется разница тогда данного кода, тут видит экземпляр

```
class Main
    {
        public function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function getClass()
        {
            require_once('new_main.php');

            print_r($obj);
        }
    }

    $main_obj = new Main();
    $main_obj->getClass();

class New_Main
    {
        public function __construct()
        {

        }
    }

    $obj = new New_Main();


На выходе 

New_Main Object
(
)
```

Comment: Так что вы ожидаете от этого кода? Main_Module содержит только пустой конструктор. Что пустой конструктор по вашему мнению должен сделать при создании экземпляра класса?

Comment: переменная obj и есть объект класса мэйн модуль разве нет?

Comment: Экземпляр класса. Но что вы все-таки ожидаете при создании экземпляра **пустого** класса?

Comment: Ну для начала хотябы увидеть что переменная obj содержит в себе экземпляр класса Main_module. На данный момент я  вижу PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: obj.

Comment: @quaresma89 правильно видишь, потому что в  `class Module` такой переменной нет

Comment: Так я подключаю файл с main модулем в котором эта переменная содержит объект, разве я не должен ее видеть?

Comment: нет не дожен. класс - это закрытая сущность. она не зря огорожена скобками... всё что не попадает в них - в нем не видно. чтобы увидеть нужно либо создать экземпляр класса Module и передать $obj как параметр, либо сделать статический метод и, опять же, передать как параметр туда

Comment: А на данный момент ты пытаешься включить в автомобиле радиоприемник, который физически находится в магазине

Comment: Хорошо в чем тогда разница следующего кода, обновлю вопрос.

Comment: Все получилось.А вы говорите не могу видеть экземпляр класса.Проблема была в том что я в 2 местах инклудил данный класс